# Range of Exponential Integral Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Define the integral operator $K: L^2(0,1) \to L^2 (0,1)$ by:
$$
Kf(x) = \int_0^1 e^{x-y} f(y) \mathrm{d}y
$$

1. Compute the range of $K$. Is it a closed set? Is the operator compact?
2. Compute the adjoint $K^{*}$ and find its kernel.
3. Verify that the equation $Kf = g$ if and only if $f \perp \ker K^*$

I am having issues with the first part of the problem. Namely, I am not sure how it is possible to characterize the range of this operator (in a tractable way).

As for the second part, I think using Fubini's theorem and rearranging the integrals should work.

Finally, I am not sure how to prove the last part. I know that $L^2 = \overline{\mathrm{ran}(A)} \oplus (\ker(A*)$ for any bounded operator $A$, but I am not sure how to apply this information.

Comment: The range is just $\operatorname{sp} \{ x \mapsto e^x \}$. So the operator has finite dimensional range.

Comment: Could you help me understand how you proved that? I was considering integration by parts but $f$ is not differentiable a-priori

Comment: $Kf = (\int_0^1 e^{-y} (y) dy )(x \mapsto e^x)$.

Comment: Wow, I just realized that the $e^x$ could be pulled out of the integral. Facepalms all around.So I guess this makes the range closed (as it is finite dimensional) and the operator compact.

Comment: No need :-) Happens to everyone.